# Can a socket instance be saved, so it can be used out of scope?

Tags: socket.io

I have never tried this, nor seen any examples that do it like this. I just want to know, if something like this is possible. I want to save the instance of socket, into some variable, so, later on it can be used outside the scope of io.on('connection', function(socket)){}. Something like this.`

```js
var s;

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  
 s = socket;  

socket.on('joinRoom', function(message){
  
  socket.join(message);

});



});


//Later on

rooms = s.rooms();
rooms = socket.rooms(s);
```

Ignore the syntax error. I just want to know, if it is logically plausible.